# Set automatically as "featured" every purchased product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

In Woocommerce, I would like when an order is mad, to set automatically as "Featured" the purchased products *(my default status for all kinds of orders is **"on-hold"**)*.

So basically, if order is "on-hold", the ordered products should turn as "Featured".

Why I want this? Because I am using the "Featured" thing not in the way as intended by WC, but instead I am displaying a custom label for the sold out product (since I keep my sold out products visible in Shop for a good number of days after the purchase).

Thus, I don't want to manually mark as Featured every product once it is sold, instead I want this to be done automatically.

Could this be done using some WC hooks in my child theme's functions.php? Any help is welcome.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will set to "featured" all the purchased products when the order status is set to "on-hold":

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'order_status_on_hold_featured_products', 20, 2);
function order_status_on_hold_featured_products( $order_id, $order ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $product->set_featured(true);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, dude! It works as intended.

However, I want the "featured" status of ordered products to change back to "not featured" when I modify the status of the order from "on-hold" into "processing" and/or "completed". 

Can you please please please adjust your function accordingly? I owe you big time!

Comment: Oh, and I also want the Catalog Visibility of such ordered products to automatically change into "Hidden" when I set the order status as "processing" and/or "completed". Would you kindly add this as well in your updated function, please? You just made my day :)

Comment: @RobertPopescu Please ask a new question (adding a link to this answer) explaining what you have actually and what you would like to have in details. Then notify me here when it's done and I will answer…